# Prove $lim_{x\to3/2}[x]=1$ using epsilon-delta

Tags: limits

Prove $lim_{x\to3/2}[x]=1$ using epsilon-delta

([x] refers to Int[x])

I fail to get a crucial inequality when trying to prove this one. Any hint?

Here's my thought:

[image]

Comment: Well, what *did* you manage to get? What are your thoughts on the problem? The more you can tell ys about your efforts and thoughts, the easier it will be for us to tailor answers to your needs.

Comment: If $1<x<2$, then what's $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: Please find my proof attached, although I'm not sure if it is right http://i.stack.imgur.com/aQDX9.jpg

Comment: For positive x, is Int[x] just the floor function?

Comment: I think for all x Int[x] is always floor function

Comment: Very nice! Though, really, you could just let $\delta=\frac12$ (as at the end of your proof) and achieve the same result.